# Can I stop Flux.range while running?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

When running from 1 to 100 in Flux.range as in the method below, it asks if it can be finished like a "For statement" depending on the condition.

```
Flux.range(0,100).map { number ->
            if (number > 10)
                // break; --> is possible?
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `takeWhile` operator for that purpose:

```kotlin
Flux.range(0,100).takeWhile { it <= 10 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I asked a question because I couldn't find it while looking for a way to stop it dynamically in the middle, like a loop, depending on certain conditions.